# Visibility of lines in a 3D plot

Tags: matplotlib

[image]

In my wishful thinking, the black line from `(0, 0, 1)` to `(1, 0, 1)` should be completely visible.

What should I do to get a sensible graph?

---

My mwe

```
In [37]: import numpy as np
    ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ...: 
    ...: fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection="3d"), constrained_layout=1)
    ...: 
    ...: x = y = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
    ...: X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    ...: Z = X+Y
    ...: 
    ...: ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
    ...: ax.plot3D([0,1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,0],[1,1,1,1,1], color='k', lw=3)
    ...: plt.show()
```

Comment: See [matplotlib's 3D FAQ](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html#my-3d-plot-doesn-t-look-right-at-certain-viewing-angles) explaining that matplotlib has a limited layering capacity and doesn't create perfect 3D visibility.  The FAQ mentions Mayavi as an alternative if full 3D functionality is desired.

Comment: @JohanC I added the Python tag to my question.  If you'd answer "Use Mayavi or …", plus a bit of argumentation and/or a piece of code, I'd be glad to accept your answer

Comment: I'm not familiar with mayavi, only with matplotlib's limitations, as it sticks to the [painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm). Feel free to self-answer the question.

Comment: @JohanC Not familiar with 3d Python software as well… I'm tempted to delete the question but I think your comment is however worth keeping the question alive.

Comment: Re the painter's algorithm, Python being Python they must be a Dutch painter, and looking at my image I'd say no one else but M.C. Escher!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this? I've added "zorder" to your plot3D code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection="3d"), constrained_layout=1)
x = y = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = X+Y
 
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
ax.plot3D([0,1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,0],[1,1,1,1,1], color='k', lw=3, zorder=3)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: _"Do you mean like this?"_ No, thank you (the `(0,1,1)` → `(1,1,1)` line MUST be behind the plane).

Answer (score 1):

What I have noticed is that, the way matplotlib currently works, any polygon is either fully in front of any other polygon, or fully behind it.

If you know the intersection lines, you could display not your original polygons, but several polygons equivalent to the original ones broken by the intersection lines. Like this, the display will be correct.

It will probably be the same with plots etc., I have not checked, but polygons should be enough in the case you are asking about.[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as a3

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection="3d")) 
blue_coords_1 = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1/2], [0, 1, 1/2] ]
blue_coords_2 = [[1, 0, 1/2], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1/2] ]

none_coords_1 = [[0, 0, 1/2], [1, 0, 1/2], [0, 1, 1/2]]
none_coords_2 = [[1, 0, 1/2], [1, 1, 1/2], [0, 1, 1/2]]

all_polys = a3.art3d.Poly3DCollection([none_coords_1, none_coords_2, blue_coords_1, blue_coords_2], facecolors=['blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red'], edgecolors=['none', 'none', 'black', 'black'])
ax.add_collection3d(all_polys)

plt.show()
```